# WDM driver and user-mode communication: best practices and callback questions

Tags: c, windows, kernel, drivers, wdm

The purpose of my driver is to notify a user-mode application about every callback that I receive, passing the data I get from those registered routines to it. The user-mode application will then print on the screen (it's a simple Win32 console application) every information it receives from kernel. I currently register three callbacks: `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx`, `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2` and `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine`. I would like to know:
**1)** Which is the "best" method for communication between kernel-mode and user-mode, considering that many processes and many images can be loaded at the same time?
**2)** Should I implement such a method for every call or should I store some information and push them to user-mode every, let's say, 0.5 seconds?
I actually use the following code for defining the IOCTL in the driver:

```
#define IOCTL_RECEIVE CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x802, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA)
```

This is the code of my DispatchDeviceControl function:

```
NTSTATUS DispatchDeviceControl(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp)
{
    KIRQL CurrentIRQL = KeGetCurrentIrql();
    DbgPrint("DispatchDeviceControl called at IRQL level: %d", CurrentIRQL);

    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpsp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    PVOID buffer = Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    ULONG inLength = irpsp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength;
    ULONG outLength = irpsp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength;
    ULONG returnLength = 0;
    pMsg PMSG = NULL;

    switch (irpsp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {   
    case IOCTL_RECEIVE:
        DbgPrint("IOCTL_RECEIVE message sent\n");
        KeWaitForSingleObject(&kEvent, Executive, KernelMode, 0, NULL);
        PMSG = (pMsg)ExInterlockedRemoveHeadList(&listhead, &spinlock);
        // Copy data to the buffer
        RtlCopyMemory((PCHAR)buffer, (PCHAR)PMSG, sizeof(Msg));
        // Release the structure
        ExFreePool(PMSG);
        // Set returnLength
        returnLength = sizeof(Msg);
        break;
    default:
        status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = returnLength;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return status;
}
```

And the code of one of my callback routines:

```
_Use_decl_annotations_
VOID prcmPsCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2(PEPROCESS Process, HANDLE ProcessId, PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO CreateInfo)
{
    // If process is exiting, just return immediately
    if (CreateInfo == NULL)
        return;

    pMsg PMSG = (pMsg)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPoolNx, sizeof(Msg), 'prcm');

    if (PMSG == NULL)
    {
        DbgPrint("PsCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2: ERROR allocating Pool space for data to be sent to user mode\n");
        return;
    }

    // Fill data
    PMSG->ParentId = NULL;
    PMSG->ProcessId = ProcessId;
    PMSG->FullImageName = NULL;

    ExInterlockedInsertHeadList(&listhead, (PLIST_ENTRY)PMSG, &spinlock);
    KeSetEvent(&kEvent, 0, FALSE);

    return;
}
```

And finally the struct definition (I included some example values, but the first element is obviously the `LIST_ENTRY`:

```
typedef struct {
    LIST_ENTRY listhead;
    HANDLE ParentId;
    HANDLE ProcessId;
    PUNICODE_STRING FullImageName;
} Msg, *pMsg;
```

For your reference, I correctly call in my `DriverEntry` function:

```
KeInitializeEvent(&kEvent, SynchronizationEvent, FALSE);
KeInitializeSpinLock(&spinlock);
InitializeListHead(&listhead);
```

In my user-mode console application, I create a thread in the main routine and in its relative thread function I constantly check for `DeviceIoControl`'s return value in order to print in real time the information that I get from the driver.
**3)** A little bit off-topic but I think it is something related: is it normal for me to miss some notifications in user-mode, with this code? Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSR wrote a great article, [The Inverted Call Model](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=94). The basic design of such a system consists of a service, a driver, and some protocol between the two.  It works with monolithic drivers as well as layered drivers and only requires that the driver be able to receive device control operations.

I would also like to mention that you are using both PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx and PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2. You should use one or the other. PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2 is supported starting with [Windows 10, version 1703 Windows Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutineex2). It provides better functionality, so I would recommend to use it if possible.

You can determine which to use by using [MmGetSystemRoutinAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-mmgetsystemroutineaddress) for dynamic usage of of PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx2, if it is unavailable then use PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx.

Comment: I was not aware of that method and as far as I understand it is the best way to achieve my goals. Thanks!